# Add functionality to an existing event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, combinations, jquery-events

I've got a set of inputs on a form that are watched for interactivity, validation, or both. In the case of both, I'm not sure how to add the second set of functionality without overriding the prior assignment.

Here's an example. I've got a field that should be watched for live validation and it should be watched for some live formatting. (Yes, I can roll them into the same function, but I'd prefer to have them separate).

Here's the validation assignment:

```
exampleField

    // for live typing
    .keyup($.debounce(500, debouncedValidation))

    // for copy-pastes and autofills
    .change(function(){
        validateInput(formInValidation, $(this));
    });
```

Additionally and independently, I'd like to run some interactive features like so:

```
exampleField

    // for live typing
    .keyup($.debounce(500, interactWithElement($(this))))

    // for copy-pastes and autofills
    .change(function(){
        interactWithElement($(this));
    });
```

I'm using the same events, so the latter overrides the former. My gut says that there's an elegant way to add a utility function inbetween, say `addEventListenerWithoutOverride()`, that looks for existing events and combines them. Is that nuts? Fictious output of said function could be something like:

```
exampleField

    .keyup(
         $.debounce(
             500,
             function(){
                 debouncedValidation();
                 interactWithElement($(this));
             });
         )
    )

    .change(function(){
        validateInput(formInValidation, $(this));
        interactWithElement($(this));
    });
```

Comment: jQuery does this by default. If you add one event handler, then another at a later point for the same event, both will be run - although the order of execution will not be guaranteed.

Comment: if you could put multiple handlers on the same element, would that solve your problem?  addEventListener()

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're kidding me - I didn't bother setting a test because I was sure jQuery was more literal out of the box. Thank you!

Comment: you could also use a proxy as your handler, then tell your proxy what to execute and in what order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `on` instead?  You can register as many listeners as you like w/o worry about overwrite.

```js
$('#bind-example').on('click', function(){alert('First click!'); });
$('#bind-example').on('click', function(){alert('Second click!'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="bind-example" href="#">Click Me!</a>
```

If I've misunderstood your question please let me know.

Comment: There's no particular reason to use `.bind()` here.  It offers no additional functionality over `.on()` or `.click()`.  In fact, if you look at the jQuery source code, all `.bind()` does is pass its arguments to  `.on()`.  And, there's this comment in the jQuery doc: "As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.".

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah of course you're right.  I blame the cold meds.  Updated

Comment: Well there you have it. Thank you!

Comment: how don't that be done with pure javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from OP's question:

> I'm using the same events, so the later overrides the former.

Actually, it doesn't. As per [jQuery's `.bind` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event
>   type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers
>   registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were
>   bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the
>   normal event propagation path.

---

So, lets leave the docs alone and test if in fact it overrides the former event or not:

```js
var overriden = true;
$("button").click(function() {
    overriden = false;
});
$("button").click(function() {
    alert("Overriden? " + overriden);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test overriden events.</button>
```

Comment: Nice explanation of the concept here - thank you for the work!